# Plugin WP Go Maps not showing

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugins

I’m trying to fix google maps that work with Pro version of Plugin WP Go Maps.
I see that some classes and styles are not being applied to the map. For example class wpgmza-initialized.

How NOT working html code are look https://ibb.co/QnMZJPf
How normal map are looking on my another project on my localhost https://ibb.co/42NFjZR

It seems that some javascript errors may affect the display of the map. But I can’t understand what exactly needs to be fixed.
[How it looks on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtjYw.png)

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed jquery error. And it's working